# Why I get html code when I send email in php?

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hi I'm developing a forgot password system in php for my project.
I wanted to send an email to my user, so they can click the link to reset their password.
But when I open my inbox, I get html text instead of a link.
I've tried other methods such as adding a header to the message, but it is still html code.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$errors = [];
$user_id = "";
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mySQLpassword',      'registration');

if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['user_id']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  if (empty($user_id)) array_push($errors, "Username or Email is required");
  if (empty($password)) array_push($errors, "Password is required");

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user_id' OR email='$user_id' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user_id;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
      array_push($errors, "Wrong credentials");
    }
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['reset-password'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  
query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
  $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "Your email is required");
  }else if(mysqli_num_rows($results) <= 0) {
    array_push($errors, "Sorry, no user exists on our system with that email");
  }
  $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50));

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset(email, token) VALUES ('$email', '$token')";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Reset your password";
    $msg = "Hi there, click on this <a href=\"new_password.php?token=" . $token . "\">link</a> to reset your password on our site";
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    $headers = "From: info@gmail.com";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    header('location: pending.php?email=' . $email);
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['new_password'])) {
  $new_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['new_pass']);
  $new_pass_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['new_pass_c']);

  $token = $_SESSION['token'];
  if (empty($new_pass) || empty($new_pass_c)) array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  if ($new_pass !== $new_pass_c) array_push($errors, "Password do not match");
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM password_reset WHERE token='$token' LIMIT 1";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)['email'];

    if ($email) {
      $new_pass = md5($new_pass);
      $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_pass' WHERE email='$email'";
      $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      header('location: index.php');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Any help will be excepted!

Comment: Is this academic code or for a production web site?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Toby, Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to @tadman's entirely correct comments about the queries, your code is also using md5 hash on your passwords (unsalted at that). md5 has not been considered secure for password storage in a very long time – and arguably never should have been. There are many far better, and easy to use, alternatives. Please do your users a favor and do not deploy this code until you addressed the database feedback and replaced your password handling.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Hi tadman
, this code is only for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.

Check "Example #5 Sending HTML email" in the [`mail` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Example ($headers is an array here):

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

Comment: When I added the code you posted, it gives me this error: ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\app_logic.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\enter_email.php(1): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app_logic.php on line 70```

Comment: It is because your variable $headers is a string. Change it to array.

Comment: Well, I still get the same thing in my browser. It does not send html email.

Comment: Check headers and content in received email (source). Gmail, for example: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? It is hard for me to follow the instruction in the link you just provided.

Comment: Try this link: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/can-i-view-the-html-source-of-an-email-sent-to-my-gmail-address
Check for "Content-type" in email source.

Comment: It gives me bunch of code. I don't see any header that is related to html content. Link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ik=e7a920374e&view=om&permmsgid=msg-f%3A1683806312936369513